# .NET Framework / Visual Studio 2013 update 5 issue

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, .net-framework-version

**Background:**
Windows 8.1
.NET Framework up to v4.6.1
Visual Studio 2013 Update 5
VS Solution targeting .NET Framework 4.0 (due to environment limitations, can't be upgraded currently)

The solution was opening fine yesterday, I was able to work in it without issues.  However, today when I open the solution I get a message saying The C# project .... is targeting ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" which is not installed on this machine and it gives me options to 
1 - Change the target to .NET Framework 4.5 (Not an option)
2 - Download the targeting pack for ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".
3 - Do not load the project

Since I'm running Windows 8, downloading .NETFramework 4 won't do any good because it won't let me install it, it says to use the add features option (which I removed/readded this feature already today).

I have downloaded the .NET Repair Tool, the NETFX Setup Verifier (which verifies .NET 4 is installed correctly), and the .NET Cleanup Tool.  None of these fix the issue.

Any ideas?  It's a work laptop so upgrading to Windows 10 isn't a timely solution either.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It recommends the *targeting pack*, not the same thing as the .NET Framework.  Targeting pack files are located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\ .NETFramework\v4.0.  You ought to be a lot more concerned about the health of the disk drive, those files don't just disappear.

Comment: I just checked and verified there are targeting packs for all .NET versions in that directory:
v3.5
v4.0
v4.0.3
v4.5
v4.5.1
v4.5.2
v4.6
v4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix the issue by running Repair on Visual Studio 2013. It found the Targeting Packs after that.